# What do ssh-keygen flags -N "" -q do?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I am following the tutorial where OP creates ssh keypair for guest VM login as ubuntu

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f id_rsa -C mycurrentfolder -N "" -q
```

what `-N "" -q` is really doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination of those two basically make the key creation run silently without any prompts to the user.

From the [***man*** page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen):

> -q silence ssh-keygen.

This is the flag to make it run silently.

> -N new_passphrase provides the new passphrase.

Despite running in silent mode it would still prompt you to enter a passphrase for the key (for a more secure encrypted key), so `-N ''` sets the passphrase to blank (so key is saved in plaintext without a passphrase.)